# How to fix height issue in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make something like this but I cannot figure out how to make left side nav bar fixed and right side content scrollable but with the size of 100% so not all content is visible at the same time

I have tried with two col bit did not work

This is what I am trying to do:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? Here we expect you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please **attempt something** then update your question to show a **specific** problem you're having in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Left side should be `fixed` position. Show me your current code

Comment: you need to explain what did you do so far, and show your example code to make it more clear what is your problem really is and what kind of solution you need.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
.leftnav{ 
        height:100vh !important;
        width: 20%;
        position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-left">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu3</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu5</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```